# Redirect to custom web page when Android App not installed instead of Play Store

Tags: javascript, android, google-play

I want to click a link that launches an app on Android. However, if the app is not installed, by default Android redirects to the Play store. I don't want this.

What I want is to be able to redirect to a custom webpage if the app is not installed. iOS seems to support this by using setTimeouts but according to this page https://vhudyma-blog.eu/open-mobile-application-from-the-browser/ there is no similar flow offered for Android.  Thank you for your help.

```js
if (isAndroid) {
      const url =
        "intent://instagram.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.instagram.android;end";

      // open the app
      // if the app isn't installed, it seems we just go to the play store
      window.location.replace(url);

    } else if (isIOS) {

      // go to the app
      window.location.replace("instagram://");

      // open the app store on a timeout. this will happen but not be seen if instagram has opened
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace(
          "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252"
        );
      }, 10000);

    } else {

      // we're not in ios or android so just go to the website
      window.location.replace("https://instagram.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a little luck with [getInstalledRelatedApps()](https://wicg.github.io/get-installed-related-apps/spec/)

```
const list = await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();
```

Here is an article about it: https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/

Even though it might [not be too wildly supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_getinstalledrelatedapps).